# .htaccess redirect: correcting image path from localhost/folder to domain.tld

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I've been struggling with this for a while.

I have a bunch of WordPress sites lifted from a local server, each originating in it's subfolder e.g. localhost/example. All image paths are broken, pointing to localhost/example instead of example.com

I need to correct all the on-page image paths from localhost/example to example.com. Files are there, paths are wrong.

Also it's a WordPress site, with it's own .htaccess redirect code (permalinks) so it is preferable the code not collide with it.

Standard WordPress .htaccess, to add to:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I've tried numerous code variations, cannot seem to get it right.

Thanks a bunch!